# read 1D barcode (code 128) direct from a pdf file

Tags: pdf, barcode

Has anyone experience with a tool (it can be also a commercial one) which can extract barcodes direct from a pdf file? The most tools I have seen can read barcodes only from images.

Thanks

Comment: Reading a barcode from a PDF will require rasterization.  There's too many ways to draw them.  Barcode fonts, line art, and raster images.  And now there's a barcode field type as well.  Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

Well, important question:

Is the barcode in a "barcode" PDF form field? If so, pretty much any PDF form capable library can do the trick. PDF barcode form fields are just text form fields with an appearance stream to display the barcode. The text value of the barcode however is exactly the data you would be looking for (and hence wouldn't need to care about the appearance stream).

If not and the barcode is on a scanned PDF (and hence in an image internally), you could use something like:

- Ghostscript http://www.ghostscript.com
- FoxIt http://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf/sdk/
- QuickPDF http://www.quickpdf.org/

to convert each page in the PDF to an image. (The list of PDF rasterizers above are under very different licensing terms, but IMHO in decreasing order of quality and maturity.) Then use one of the many barcode image libraries on the image as a whole.